# I want to print bubblesorted array with random numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, console-application

I've created an array called place and filled all 100 indexes with random numbers from 1 to 100 and run a bubblesort on the array. When I want to print out in console, it gives nothing. It's all blank. Mind, I'm pretty new to C# and programming in general, so if you can tell me why this thing doesn't print my sorted array, I'd be grateful.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] place = new int[100];
        int spot = random.Next(1, 101);
        for (int i = 0; i < place.Length; i++)
        {
            spot = random.Next(1, 101);
            place[i] = spot;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= place.Length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < place.Length - 1; i++) 
            {
                if (place[j] > place[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = place[j + 1];
                    place[j + 1] = place[j];
                    place[j] = temp;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(place[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Fix the typo in your second loop `i++` --> `j++`

Comment: i <= place.Length should be just <, else you always get exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two typos:

```
for (int i = 0; i < place.Length; i++) // should be <, not <= (throws exception)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < place.Length - 1; j++) // should be j++ instead of i++
    {
        if (place[j] > place[j + 1])
        {
            int temp = place[j + 1];
            place[j + 1] = place[j];
            place[j] = temp;
        }    
    }

    Console.WriteLine(place[i]); // is it necessary?
}

Console.WriteLine();

for (int i = 0; i < place.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(place[i]);
}
```

I also added code that prints the whole array, to see if this sorting works (and it does).

Comment: I had tried your solution before and it didn't work, but I hadn't caught those typos since I didn't get any errors, but thanks anyway for answering my question. I know I'm still a newbie at this, so thanks for taking time to help me :)